# Connecting Pentaho to mysql database (localhost)

Tags: mysql, connection, localhost, pentaho

I download last version of MySQL jdbc connector (mysql-connector-java-8.0.13) and I put it in the following folders:

- C:\Users\maria\Desktop\report-designer\report-designer\lib
  and
- C:\Users\maria\Desktop\report-designer\report-designer\lib\jdbc

And it shows me the following error:

```
    Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed.
    org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver


    org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
    Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
```

While, when I introduced the old version file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin) at the same folders as said before (above). Pentaho shows me the following error:

```
    Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
    Could not create connection to database server.

    org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
    Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
```

can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I manage to solve the error.

I put my jdbc connector (mysql-connector-java-8.0.13) into the following folder:

- C:\Users\maria\Desktop\report-designer\report-designer\lib an

And I change the name of my MySQL DB.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- Stop Report Designer
- Remove it from the 'C:\Users\maria\Desktop\report-designer\report-designer\lib\jdbc' directory
- Restart Report designer

You can only have one jdbc driver in the lib directory for the db.  So when you add the 5.1.34 driver, you are adding a second MySQL driver, causing that second error.

Comment: Hi @mbegs, 

Thank you for your answer but it didn't work.

Comment: The error that appears  now is the following:



`Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Could not create connection to database server.


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database`